# Changing Auth0Lock to Auth0-js

Tags: angular, auth0

In my Angular4 project I am trying to migrate from auth0-lock to auth0-js. For that I created the AuthService class that you can see in the documentation and install the auth0-js package by doing

```
npm install --save auth0-js
```

But, when I run my app I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'WebAuth' of undefined
```

If I download the example project that you can find in quick start I do not get this error, but I do not know what else I have to do.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Seems to work when I run the example project, but I am trying to add this into a project based on the .Net Core Angular SPA template from Microsoft. Haven't tried adding it to a fresh Angular project though. Let us know what you come up with!

Comment: Same problem, all my test broke that had AuthService as a provider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just saw this solution below and it works:

`import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44160476/2975759

Also you may want to install the `Types`. I had issues with my IDE not seeing the methods and properties of the Auth0 package.

```
npm install @types/auth0-js --save-dev
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, your solution worked, I marked it as accepted. Just one question that you may know the answer, how can I add the app_metadata and user_metadata in the token?

Comment: Depending on what sort of rules you want to add to app_metadata or user_metadata, in your Auth0 Manager dashboard you need to create **Rules**. For example I wanted to update the user_metadata to have user roles for each user. So I utilized the rule **set roles to a user**. https://auth0.com/rules/roles-creation