# Error while using the Auth0 spa quickstart

Tags: angular, angular2-services, auth0

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 web app that will use Auth0 for user authentication.

I followed the [quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/getting-started) at the Auth0 website, but I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'WebAuth' of undefined at new AuthService (auth.service.ts:9)`, even though AuthService is declared.

Am I missing something? Any help is very much appreciated.

This is my code

//app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(public auth: AuthService) {
        auth.handleAuthentication();
    }
}
```

//auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import auth0 from 'auth0-js';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
        clientID: '*****',
        domain: '*****',
        responseType: 'token id_token',
        audience: '******',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/callback',
        scope: 'openid'
    });

    constructor(public router: Router) { }

    public login(): void {
        this.auth0.authorize();
    }

    public handleAuthentication(): void {
        this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
            if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
                window.location.hash = '';
                this.setSession(authResult);
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            } else if (err) {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

    private setSession(authResult): void {
        // Set the time that the access token will expire at
        const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
    }

    public logout(): void {
        // Remove tokens and expiry time from localStorage
        localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('expires_at');
        // Go back to the home route
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }

    public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
        // Check whether the current time is past the
        // access token's expiry time
        const expiresAt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expires_at'));
        if (new Date().getTime() &lt; expiresAt) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

//app.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header" *ngIf="auth" >
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Auth0 - Angular</a>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin"
                    routerLink="/">
                Home
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin"
                    *ngIf="!auth.isAuthenticated()"
                    (click)="auth.login()">
                Log In
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-margin"
                    *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()"
                    (click)="auth.logout()">
                Log Out
            </button>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<main class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to import it this way:

`import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';`

Comment: using the last line worked for me! thank you so much

Comment: in case this helps someone - I also had to remove the script import from the index.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any mistake or typo. Did you do the

`# installation with npm
npm install --save auth0-js`

and the import with:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/auth0-js/build/auth0.js"></script>`

in the `index.html` or if you use angular-cli in the `.angular-cli.json` under `["app"]["scripts"]`?

`{
    "project": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta.24",
        "name": "angular-src"
    },
    "apps": [{
        "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
--> INSERT HERE <--
        ],`

Comment: I had installed it using npm and had the script imported in my index html  using the cdn `<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0/8.6/auth0.min.js"></script>`, but now I removed the cdn import in the index.html and added `import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';`. now, with no import in the index.html, it's working. thank you though!